# Changing Tab-Order (Focus) in a cocoa-App

Tags: swift, cocoa, focus, responder-chain

I have a simple view with 4 textfields tf1 - tf4.

I want to set the initial focus on tf2, that works fine.

Then I want, that tf1 gets focus, then tf2 again - that does not work, the focus cycles through all 4 textfields.

I tried like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear()
{ super.viewWillAppear()
  tf2.becomeFirstResponder()

  tf2.nextKeyView = tf1
  tf1.nextKeyView = tf2
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Don't call `becomeFirstResponder`. "Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder: method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly."

Comment: Set `initialFirstResponder` of the window to `tf2`.

Comment: what is the best place to set the NSWindows firstResponder? Is also viewWillAppear OK? How can I get the window in the viewcontroller?

Comment: Thanks!! <br>    With:  self.view.window!.initialFirstResponder = tf2 it works fine

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Willeke:

It works fine with:

```
override func viewWillAppear()
{ super.viewWillAppear()
  tf2.nextKeyView = tf1
  tf1.nextKeyView = tf2      
  self.view.window!.initialFirstResponder = tf2
}
```